# netduino check email

Tags: c#, gmail, email-client, netduino

I see lot of examples on how to send email with a  but I'm looking to run an action checking an email account.

Does anyone know if that can be done (im sure it can) and point me to some examples?

Comment: Are you attempting to read from a POP-enabled GMail account, use IMAP, or screen scrape?

Comment: I would prefer gmail and it only needs to read so pop is probably just fine (low overhead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code online but  "POP3_Client" isn't recognized and I don't see any refrences to add it

```
 POP3_Client Mailbox = new POP3_Client(new >>>>IntegratedSocket<<<<<("pop.yourisp.com", 110), "yourusername", "yourpassword");
            Mailbox.Connect();
            Debug.Print("Message count: " + Mailbox.MessageCount.ToString());
            Debug.Print("Box size in bytes: " + Mailbox.BoxSize.ToString());

            uint[] Id, Size;
            Mailbox.ListMails(out Id, out Size);
            for (int Index = 0; Index < Id.Length; ++Index)
            {
                string[] Headers = Mailbox.FetchHeaders(Id[Index], new string[] { "subject", "from", "date" });
                Debug.Print("Mail ID " + Id[Index].ToString() + " is " + Size[Index].ToString() + " bytes");
                Debug.Print("Subject: " + Headers[0]);
                Debug.Print("From: " + Headers[1]);
                Debug.Print("Date: " + Headers[2]);
                Debug.Print("======================================================================");
            }

            Mailbox.Close();
```

Comment: Seems like POP3_Client is part of the NETMF Toolbox at https://netmftoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toolbox.NETMF.NET.POP3_Client

Comment: Im halfway there I installed the netfmtoolbox framework, then I made a refrence to the toolbox.netmf.net.pop3_client.dll and i have everything but the simplenetmfsockts object

Comment: Did you add a reference to `Toolbox.NETMF.Core.dll` too (seems that `SimpleSocket` is located there)?

Comment: Sorry to keep moving the target on you but It seems the updated example has removed "simplesockets" with intgrated (see code change above) but I sill can't get it to recognise  integrated sockets. I have added "toolbox.netmf.core" toobox.netmf.net.core and toolbox.netmf.net.pop3_client" still nothing

Comment: Looks like `SimpleSocket` is an abstract class now, whereas `IntegratedSocket` is a derived class, so try adding `Toolbox.NETMF.NET.Integrated.dll` as well.

Comment: looks like we might have a winner

Comment: Nice that I could help a little bit. (But actually you answered the question yourself by posting the code snippet ;)

Comment: I think the code is working but im still giggling out some of the connection string to connect to gmail.  post an "answer" to this post and ill give you the bounty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21925/discussion-between-crash893-and-jcoder)

Comment: Any idea on the connection string I'm using pop.gmail.com port 995 but the code appears to just freeze or exit out

Comment: According to Google Mail's documentation/help: pop.gmail.com on port 995 requires SSL which might not be available on NETMF (might depend on version/device). Can you trace the network traffic with a tool like Wireshark?

Comment: @Crash893 Did my answer not help? ;(

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can get a gmail inbox.

**OpenPop**

**If you do want to just use POP, and you do not mind using external libraries, this looks like the best/easiest way to go.** OpenPop allows you to access a secure/unsecure email account and lets you choose the port. See [this post](http://www.floresense.com/resc_center/?art=1407) to get started.

> OpenPop is an open source C#.NET code bundle that implements mail
>   fetching and parsing. As of this writing, it only uses Microsoft .NET
>   framework libraries to do the required. But for accessing secure pop
>   servers, openPop can be extended by using some SSL library.

For example, to access Gmail via Pop:

```
POPClient poppy = new POPClient();
poppy.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
poppy.Authenticate(username@gmail.com, "password");
int Count = poppy.GetMessageCount();
if (Count > 0)
{
   for (int i = Count; i >= 1; i -= 1)
   {
     OpenPOP.MIMEParser.Message m = poppy.GetMessage(i, false);
     //use the parsed mail in variable 'm'
   }
}
```

**TcpClient POP3:**

To retrieve emails from any provider via Pop3, you could use a TcpClient. With Gmail, it is only slightly different, because Gmail uses SSL and port 995 for POP. There is an example of that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/satalajmore/archive/2007/12/19/asp-net-read-email.aspx):

```
// create an instance of TcpClient 

TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();     

// HOST NAME POP SERVER and gmail uses port number 995 for POP 

tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995); 

// This is Secure Stream // opened the connection between client and POP Server

System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());

// authenticate as client  

 sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");
```

**Gmail Atom Feed:**

The first way is to use `GmailAtomFeed`, which is part of the [C# .Net Gmail Tools](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/CSharpGmail). The website says:

> The GmailAtomFeed class provides a simple object layer for
>   programmatic access to gmails atom feed. In just a couple lines of
>   code the feed will be retreived from gmail and parsed. After that the
>   entries can be accessed through an object layer
>   AtomFeedEntryCollection, plus access to the raw feed and the feeds
>   XmlDocument is also available.

And this is an example of how you use it:

```
   // Create the object and get the feed 
   RC.Gmail.GmailAtomFeed gmailFeed = new RC.Gmail.GmailAtomFeed("username", "password"); 
   gmailFeed.GetFeed(); 

   // Access the feeds XmlDocument 
   XmlDocument myXml = gmailFeed.FeedXml 

   // Access the raw feed as a string 
   string feedString = gmailFeed.RawFeed 

   // Access the feed through the object 
   string feedTitle = gmailFeed.Title; 
   string feedTagline = gmailFeed.Message; 
   DateTime feedModified = gmailFeed.Modified; 

   //Get the entries 
   for(int i = 0; i &lt; gmailFeed.FeedEntries.Count; i++) { 
      entryAuthorName = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].FromName; 
      entryAuthorEmail = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].FromEmail; 
      entryTitle = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].Subject; 
      entrySummary = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].Summary; 
      entryIssuedDate = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].Received; 
      entryId = gmailFeed.FeedEntries[i].Id; 
   }
```

**IMAP**

Another way, if you are not LIMITED to POP, is to use IMAP. With IMAP, you can connect to a SSL server and choose a port along with that:

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com", 993);
    imap.Login("angel_y@company.com", "xyx***"); // MailID As Username and Password

    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uids = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.Unseen);
    foreach (long uid in uids)
    {
        string eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
        IMail message = new MailBuilder()
            .CreateFromEml(eml);

        Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine(message.TextDataString);
    }
    imap.Close(true);
}
```

Comment: Not directly because the question was constrained to pop via gmail running on a netdirno. the code posted above wont run on a netdrino board. BUT  the idea of checking the atom feed is something I will try. so ill throw you a +1 for that